# Delete a folder inside zip in php

Tags: php, zip

I've a ZIP file (`skins.zip`) having the following structure:

```
yellow  
  |_resources  
  |_theme  
  |_codes
```

I need to delete folder called `theme/` inside the `skins.zip`. I've tried the following code but didn't worked.

```php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('skins.zip') === TRUE) {
        $zip->deleteName('yellow/theme/');
        $zip->close();
}
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What exactly went wrong?  Have you enabled error reporting to investigate possible problems?

Comment: it shows nothing and still the folder exists after the code execution.

Comment: $x=$zip->deleteName('yellow/theme/'); var_dump($x); least you know then

Comment: Did you check file permissions? If i remember correctly file needs to be writable. I was experiencing same problems several months ago and i remember it was solved automatically when i changed file permissions.

Comment: @Dagon: It returns "bool(false) "

Comment: @ioseb: the zip file has 0644 and folder in which it is placed set to 0755. is there any issue with these permissions?

Comment: try using a recursive delete? maybe it doesn't allow folder deletion if it has contents in it? php.net's manual doesn't say much about it and I didn't use it myself before. just a guess.

Comment: yeah, i've some files inside the folder, is this issue?

Comment: Try also to use an else statement, maybe the zip file isn't even opened ?! (else{echo "failed to open ZIP";})

Comment: try the path as "`/yellow/theme`" not "`./yellow/theme`" or "`yellow/theme`".

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: if it's not opened means, then its not present. here its returns true for that statement.

Comment: @tpaksu: It deletes empty directory, problems with non-empty direcotry..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just the following code and left the `print_r` output for you to understand what's going on:

```php
$z = new ZipArchive;
$folder_to_delete = "gifresizer/resized/";  //folder to delete relative to root
if($z->open("gifresizer.zip")===TRUE){      //zip file name
    print_r($z);
    for($i=0;$i<$z->numFiles;$i++){
        $entry_info = $z->statIndex($i);
        print_r($entry_info);
        if(substr($entry_info["name"],0,strlen($folder_to_delete))==$folder_to_delete){
            $z->deleteIndex($i);
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs something like this:

```
ZipArchive Object
(
    [status] => 0
    [statusSys] => 0
    [numFiles] => 10
    [filename] => C:\xampp\htdocs\test\zipdelete\gifresizer.zip
    [comment] => 
)
Array
(
    [name] => gifresizer/
    [index] => 0
    [crc] => 0
    [size] => 0
    [mtime] => 1339360746
    [comp_size] => 0
    [comp_method] => 0
)
Array
(
    [name] => gifresizer/frames/
    [index] => 1
    [crc] => 0
    [size] => 0
    [mtime] => 1328810540
    [comp_size] => 0
    [comp_method] => 0
)
Array
(
    [name] => gifresizer/gifresizer.php
    [index] => 2
    [crc] => 1967518989
    [size] => 18785
    [mtime] => 1328810430
    [comp_size] => 3981
    [comp_method] => 8
)

etc..
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. works great (+1).  Just note that if you want to extract the contents after removing your unwanted indexes, you will need to $z->close() the archive and re-open it before extracting.  Otherwise your extracted contents may be only a partial extract of all the remaining files in the archive.

Comment: Thanks. Yes closing is important on every stream because there's a chance you might not open it again as well.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$zip->deleteName('./yellow/theme/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I used (based on Taha Paksu's answer), with the php8 flavour:

```
/**
 * Removes an entry from an existing zip file.
 *
 * The name is the relative path of the entry to remove (relative to the zip's root).
 *
 *
 * @param string $zipFile
 * @param string $name
 * @param bool $isDir
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public static function deleteFromZip(string $zipFile, string $name, bool $isDir)
{
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    if (true !== ($res = $zip->open($zipFile))) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Could not open the zipFile: " . $zip->getStatusString());
    }


    $name = rtrim($name, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    if (true === $isDir) {
        $name .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $info = $zip->statIndex($i);
        if (true === str_starts_with($info['name'], $name)) {
            $zip->deleteIndex($i);
        }
    }
    $zip->close();
}
```